# how to get varible to ajax content from jq plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax

In my page I have a ajax loaded content.
The content is dynamic and contains buttons to upload files through my custom ajaxupload plugin.
I use delegate method because is a ajax content but I have a problem to pass a variable to my ajax plugin.
Infact when I try to get ids this returns undefined

```
ids : $('ul.active').attr('ids') <-- undefined
```

MY SCENARIO

HTML

```
<div id="load-ajax"></div><!-- ajax load content -->
<input type="file" id="inputUpload" style="display:none" /><!-- for upload file -->
```

load.php - Ajax loaded dynamic content buttons

```
    <div class=\"btn-group\">
        <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" aria-expanded=\"false\">
            <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip\"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class=\"dropdown-menu\" role=\"menu\" ids=\"1\" >
            <li><a href=\"\" class=\"upload \">Upload</a></li>
            <li><a href=\"\" class=\"edit\">Edit</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class=\"btn-group\">
        <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" aria-expanded=\"false\">
            <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip\"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class=\"dropdown-menu\" role=\"menu\" ids=\"4\" >
            <li><a href=\"\" class=\"upload \">Upload</a></li>
            <li><a href=\"\" class=\"edit\">Edit</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class=\"btn-group\">
        <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" aria-expanded=\"false\">
            <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip\"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class=\"dropdown-menu\" role=\"menu\" ids=\"3\" >
            <li><a href=\"\" class=\"upload \">Upload</a></li>
            <li><a href=\"\" class=\"edit\">Edit</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

JS

```
// First call
loadPage();

function loadPage() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: load.php,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#load-ajax').html(data);
        },
        complete: function() {
            //callAjaxUpload();
        }
    });
}

$('#load-ajax).on('click', '.upload', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(e.currentTarget).closest('ul').addClass('active');
    $('#inputUpload').trigger('click');
});

$('#inputUpload').ajaxUpload({
    allowed_types   : ['pdf', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'bmp'],
    extra_fields : { ids : $('ul.active').attr('ids') }, <-- undefined
    onFinish : function() { 
       console.log($('ul.active').attr('ids')); <-- return the right ids value 
       loadPage(); 
    }
});
```

CUSTOM AJAX UPLOAD PLUGIN

```
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {

    // Function-level strict mode syntax
    'use strict';

    $.fn.ajaxUpload = function(options) {

        var defaults = {
            num_files       : 0,
            max_files       : 18,
            max_concurrent  : 10,
            max_filesize    : 1024 * 4096,
            php_max_size    : 1024 * 8192,
            allowed_types   : ['jpeg','jpg'],
            ajax_url        : 'ajax-php/action.php',
            var_name        : 'file',
            extra_fields    : {},
            onFinish        : function() {}
        };

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {

            var $this = $(this);

            $this.on('change', function() {

                var files = $this[0].files;
                var len = files.length;
                var items = 0;
                var diff_files = parseInt(defaults.max_files - defaults.num_files - len);

                if(diff_files < 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                if(!maxUploadFiles(len, defaults.max_concurrent)) {
                    return false;
                }
                var formdata = new FormData();

                jQuery.each(files, function(i, file) {
                    if(!isOverSized(file, defaults.max_filesize)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if(!isAllowedTypes(file, defaults.allowed_types)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if(!totalFilesSize(file, defaults.php_max_size)) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    formdata.append(defaults.var_name + '['+i+']', file);
                    items++;
                });

                // Append extra data to formdata
                $.each(defaults.extra_fields, function(name, value) {
                    formdata.append(name, value);
                });

                // Check that files have passed all test
                if (len != items) { return false; }

                $.ajax({
                    url: defaults.ajax_url,
                    data: formdata,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    beforeSend: function () {
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        defaults.onFinish.call(this);
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        totalSize = 0;

                        //Reset input data
                        //$this.replaceWith($this.val('').clone(true));
                    }
                });

            });
       });
    };

    var totalSize = 0;

    function totalFilesSize(file, php_max_size) {
        totalSize += file.size;
        if(totalSize > php_max_size) {
            totalSize = 0;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function maxUploadFiles(len, max_concurrent) {
        if(len > max_concurrent) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function isAllowedTypes(file, allowed_types) {
        var ext = file.name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        if(jQuery.inArray(ext, allowed_types) < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function isOverSized(file, max_filesize) {
        if(file.size > max_filesize) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

I have to modify something in my ajaxUpload plugin?
How would I go about taking the variable correctly?
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Try: `$('ul.active').attr('id')`.

There is no such attribute called "ids".

EDIT: Sorry that I rushed into answer without reading your question properly.

If you take a look at this jsfiddle you can clearly see that $('ul.active').attr('ids') statement should work
https://jsfiddle.net/o3ejzwow/

So the only reason why this statement would return undefined would be when there is no "active" class appended to any of the "ul" elements.

P.S: I would advice you to use "data-" before any custom(user defined) attributes and use .prop instead of .attr post 1.8 version of jquery.

Comment: that there is ! <ul class=\"dropdown-menu\" role=\"menu\" ids=\"4\" >

Comment: can you tell me which version of jquery pluggin are you using?

Comment: I use jquery-2.1.1. a) My problem is that my custom plugin upload not get "active" class If this is added in a ajax loaded content. b) attr() works properly seen that on onFinish it return the right result (then the class is successfully added !). I hope it is not a problem of my custom ajaxupload plugin. Thank for your help.

Comment: Yes imo active class is not getting appended to the ul element hence why that particular jquery function is returning undefined. And yes attr() works perfectly but according to jquery documentation its deprecated and they insist on developers to use prop() in its stead.